# Error al desplegar en jboss 7.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, jboss-as-7, log4j2

estoy trabajando en un desarrollo que utiliza spring boot 2.7.14, el resultado de este proyecto es un artefacto war el cual planeo desployarlo en un Jboss 7.4, pero cuando intento hacer la carga de dicho war el jboss se la vive devolviendome errores sobre problemas con log4j2. Ya intente hacer distintas configuraciones pero siempre terminan devolviendome distintos errores sobre lo mismo:

ERROR 1

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
>     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
> ```

ERROR 2

> ```
> {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"AUT.war\".undertow-deployment" =>
> ```
>
> "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY"}}

ERROR 3

> {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
> {"jboss.deployment.unit."AUT.war".undertow-deployment" =>
> "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the
> classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation
> (class org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory loaded from
> jar:file:/jboss/jboss-eap-7.4_MARCS/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar!/).
> If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to
> prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml:
> org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory

Investigando parece que mi configuracion de pom.xml es correcta, pero pese a eso no me deja deplegar mi proyecto. Alguien sabe cómo puede resolverse?

Este es mi pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>mx.com.aut</groupId>
    <artifactId>aut</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aut</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starters -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Exclude Tomcat and Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RESTO DE DEPENDENCIAS -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- CONFIGURACIONES -->
    </build>

</project>
```